# Selenium - Returning the xpath or CSS path of an element found by LinkText

Tags: c#, css, selenium, xpath

Is there a possible method or way to can grab the absolute xpath or css path from doing a FindElement by LinkText?  Example:

```
FindElement(By.LinkText("LinkTextThat'sClickable"));
```

Comment: Can you share `HTML` code sample for better understanding of your issue?

Comment: I have actually found the solution to my issue that was causing me problems, but I'm still curious if it's possible to pull the absolute xpath from a FindElement by LinkText. (I will update my question accordingly).

Comment: Why you would want absolute? and not relative.

Answer (score 0):

how about getting the node by using ancestors::node() and then working your way with the results?

Answer (score -2):

Hey you can try getting `xpath` attribute of that `specific element` Hope this can solve your problem.

```
FindElement(By.LinkText("LinkTextThat'sClickable")).GetAttribute("xpath");;
```

Comment: Are you sure? :) Did you try it? Any proofs of why this actually should work?

Comment: That is not a valid "attribute."